# Select con when

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Necesito hacer un select donde al mostrar el registro de empleados (id_empleado) si es null muestre (sin empleado) pero los demás que no sean null muestre el registro del id_empleado

```
(case when id_empleado is null then 'Sin empleado')
```

este codigo funciona a medias ya que solo muesta los null

```
select id_pedido,nombre,cantidad,fecha_pedido,
(case when id_empleado is null then 'Sin empleado'
      else id_empleado
 end) from (select pedidos.id_pedido,productos.nombre,
detalles_pedido.cantidad,pedidos.fecha_pedido,empleados.id_empleado 
 from detalles_pedido left join productos on detalles_pedido.id_producto=productos.id_producto 
                right join pedidos on detalles_pedido.id_pedido=pedidos.id_pedido
                 left join empleados on pedidos.id_empleado=empleados.id_empleado) tabl;
```

Comment: Y cual es la pregunta? mas alla de que te recomendaria ver la funcion COALESCE (que esta en todas las bases de datos)

Comment: Prueba quitando toda esa subconsulta y prueba si funciona el CASE solo, según veo el problema no es el CASE , también prueba poniendo los alias de las tablas antes de cada columna que quieres mostrar en el select principal y en el case.

Comment: Ya quite la subconsulta, pero el problemas es el mismo, me da el resultado deseado en donde se cumple el when, pero todo los demás registro lo muestra en null cuando quisiera que mostrara el registro que ya tiene

Comment: Esta consulta `select empleados.id_empleado from detalles_pedido left join productos on detalles_pedido.id_producto=productos.id_producto right join pedidos on detalles_pedido.id_pedido=pedidos.id_pedido left join empleados on pedidos.id_empleado=empleados.id_empleado`  ¡devuelve id_Empleados? A priori, el case when esta bien formado. Si la consulta devuelve valores, debería de funcionarte bien. Pero una estructura que tiene un `left` un `right` y un `left` quizá requiera de un replanteamiento. Además....

Comment: Cuál es el motor. mySql o postgresql? Y lo más importante, si creas un [ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) podrás obtener una ayuda adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para comenzar, y siguiendo el principio de mantener las cosas simples ([KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)), no es necesaria una sub-consulta, lo que deseas puedes hacerlo sin ella.

Luego, asumiendo que tu diseñó es más o menos el típico, no necesitas usar `case`, puedes valerte de la [función `coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce). Mi ejemplo depende de que:

- Exista una columna `Nombre` en la tabla Empledos (no veo sentido a traer una cadena sobre una columna que asumo es numérica, como `id_empleado`).
- Esa columna nombre tiene el atributo `not null`, por lo que no habría empleados sin nombre.

```
select   pedidos.id_pedido
       , productos.nombre
       , detalles_pedido.cantidad
       , pedidos.fecha_pedido
       , empleados.id_empleado
       , coalesce(empleados.Nombre, 'Sin empleado') as Empleado
  from detalles_pedido
       left join productos on detalles_pedido.id_producto = productos.id_producto
      right join pedidos on detalles_pedido.id_pedido = pedidos.id_pedido
       left join empleados on pedidos.id_empleado = empleados.id_empleado
;
```

Si hay integridad referencial entre la tabla `detalles_pedido` y `pedidos`, cambia el `join` a dicha tabla por `inner join`. Si no la tienes, considera agregarla, pues no parece tener sentido tener líneas de pedido sin encabezado.